# Java spring mapped object contains a property not returned by result set

Tags: java, spring, entity

Java spring mapped object contains a property not returned by result set

I have an entity `User` with properties:

```java
@id long id
String name
String email
int age
```

Sometimes, I need as result only `id` and `name`. The SQL looks like:

```sql
select user.name, user.id 
  from user 
  where "some condition";
```

The result set is mapped to user class.

In this case, I get an error like:

```
2023-09-28T19:29:00.596+03:00 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  WARN 9304 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2023-09-28T19:29:00.596+03:00 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= ERROR 9304 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'email' not found.
2023-09-28T19:29:00.629+03:00 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO 9304 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.a.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor : More than one TaskExecutor bean found within the context, and none is named 'taskExecutor'. Mark one of them as primary or name it 'taskExecutor' (possibly as an alias) in order to use it for async processing: [deleteUserExecutor, exportDataExecutor]
2023-09-28T19:29:00.632+03:00 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= ERROR 9304 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to find column position by name: email [Column 'email' not found.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'email' not found.
```

So basically I need to change SQL to look like:

```sql
select user.name, user.id, null email, null age
  from user 
  where "some condition";
```

...in order to avoid the error. The other option is to define another entity to match result set (object with `@id long id`, `string name`)...

Is there any other way to avoid this?

Comment: If you are using Spring data as an ORM, and you have defined all the expected columns as properties, I don't see how this is a problem? Once you get the result set back from the database, map only the fields you need to transfer to the client. This is refered to as mapping a DAO (database access object) to a DTO (data transfer object). I would only define a database model aka DAO once.

Comment: Why are you writing SQL? Why not use Spring Data JPA, define a `UserRepository` for your `UserEntity`, and then just call `userRepository.findById(long id)`?

Comment: Guys, stay with question. That "simple and trivial" sql is in fact several joins and multiple conditions; pretty hard to use entity joins and so; it is needed to use a sql but the results set is a two column set : name + id.
Of course I can use different objects but I would like to avoid that.